# unsold token in a crowdsale ethereum

Tags: tokens, crowdsale

I'm new in the solidity coding.
I'm trying to retrieve the unsold tokens from a crowdsale contract.
I add the command `tokenReward.transfer(beneficiary, amountRaised);`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract RS1 {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 0;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    // This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    // This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    function RS1(
    ) public {
        totalSupply = 100000;  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
        name = "RS1";                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = "RS1";                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` on behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens on your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens on your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
     *
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens from other account
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and below the crowdsale

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface token {
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount);
}

contract CRD2 {
address public beneficiary;
uint public fundingGoal;
uint public amountRaised;

uint public amountToken;

uint public deadline;
uint public price;
token public tokenReward;
mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
bool fundingGoalReached = false;
bool crowdsaleClosed = false;
event GoalReached(address recipient, uint totalAmountRaised);
event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

event TokenTransfer(address backer, uint amountToken, bool isContribution);

/**
 * Constrctor function
 *
 * Setup the owner
 */
function CRD2(
    address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
    uint fundingGoalInEthers,
    uint durationInMinutes,
    uint etherCostOfEachToken,
    address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
) {
    beneficiary = 0xAb44F092f1E01E8f91DfE9035A09461B928eDFb7;
    fundingGoal = 0.1 * 1 ether;
    deadline = now + 10 * 1 minutes;
    price = 0.1 * 1 ether;
    tokenReward = token(0x390fc971502fb5236570ba28c81e0Ba71AC55910);
}

/**
 * Fallback function
 *
 * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
 */
function () payable {
    require(!crowdsaleClosed);
    uint amount = msg.value;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
    amountRaised += amount;
    tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
    FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
}

modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

/**
 * Check if goal was reached
 *
 * Checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign
 */
function checkGoalReached() afterDeadline {
    if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
        fundingGoalReached = true;
        GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
    }
    crowdsaleClosed = true;
}


/**
 * Withdraw the funds
 *
 * Checks to see if goal or time limit has been reached, and if so, and the funding goal was reached,
 * sends the entire amount to the beneficiary. If goal was not reached, each contributor can withdraw
 * the amount they contributed.
 */
function safeWithdrawal() afterDeadline {
    if (!fundingGoalReached) {
        uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
        if (amount > 0) {
            if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
            } else {
                balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
            }
        }
    }

    if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
        if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
            FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            TokenTransfer(beneficiary, amountToken, false);
        } else {
            //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
            fundingGoalReached = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

but it doesn't work.
Is there someone could help me?
Thanks

Comment: There seems to be some confusion between tokens and ether... `amountRaised` is used as the amount of ether transferred as well as the amount of tokens transferred. It seems that one of those must be wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I think you may be right. Do you have any suggestion to receive the unsold tokens? tks

Comment: Do you have a variable that keeps track of how many tokens are unsold?

Comment: no... What kind of variable I could put in the code to keep track of this?

Comment: @Rajesh's answer is a good way to go without adding a variable. Just transfer the remaining balance.

Comment: I tried, but when I compile it with Solidity Remix IDE, I receive the error message "Memeber "balanceOf" not found or not visible after the argument-dependent lookup in contract token". And I don't understand :(

Comment: Share your code. ERC20 tokens have a `balanceOf` function. Is `tokenReward` an ERC20 token? How is its type defined? Is there an interface? Another contract?

Comment: Ok... below the Token code

Comment: It's too long... However It's very similar to the code explained in https://www.ethereum.org/token and then the crowdsale https://ethereum.org/crowdsale. As you can see I'm new in this worls :)

Comment: Can you not edit your post to include the code?

Comment: The similar code I can see at ethereum.org/crowdsale is just missing a definition for `balanceOf`. Add `function balanceOf(address) external returns (uint256);` to the `token` interface.

Comment: I added, as you suggested. Now I try

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this. This transfer all remaining tokens in the contract to the beneficiary(msg.sender in this case).

```
tokenReward.transfer(beneficiary, tokenReward.balanceOf(this));
```

**Edit**

Have the following line of code added in the token interface

```
function balanceOf(address _owner);
```

Comment: I tried but When I compile it I receive the error message "Memeber "balanceOf" not found or not visible after the argument-dependent lookup in contract token".

Comment: have edited the answer, Try now.